# Occupation groups for a country simulation game

Tags: game-design

I'm trying to create citizen occupation groups or job classes for a country-management game I'm developing. I want it to be inclusionary but also very basic.

I did some research but all job lists I got contains more than 20 job types like farming, mining, education, law but It's too many for my game's setting and It still doesn't include every workforce. I need wider spectrum of jobs but I'm having trouble to categorize them, like labour, public service etc...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remember that not every problem you need to solve in making a game is one in which game developers are experts. We can help you with designing & implementing game mechanics, but when you're choosing data to fit your game's setting, consulting experts in that specific subject matter is a better bet. Here, you probably want to talk to a demographer. Then, once you've chosen your representative set of occupations, if you have any trouble designing & implementing their game rules, that's when talking to a game development expert would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are approaching this problem from the wrong angle.

First, forget about inclusivity and simulationism for a moment. Make up your mind about what experience you want to create from a gameplay perspective. What aspects of country management do you want to simulate? What situations do you want your player to experience? A good tool in this conceptualization phase can be to write **player stories**. Describe the events of a typical game session as you imagine it from the perspective of the player.

Then check what occupational groups you need to create that game experience. You will now see what dividing lines make sense in the context of your particular game and which do not.

When you start prototyping your game, try to keep it as simple as possible. Start out with the bare minimum of groups you need to create the experience you are looking for. Don't worry yet about your game not having enough gameplay breadth - feature creep will set in later anyway.

I am looking forward to playing your game.